# Does uneven sampling during 3 time periods violate independence for ANOVA?

Tags: anova, independence, assumptions

A continuous variable is measured at 7 AM, 2 PM, and 7PM, over the course of 2.5 months (summer).
An animal is being periodically observed, while the site is monitored.
The observation periods are for one hour.  No two observations periods occur on the same day.
48 days were selected for 7 AM, 52 days for 2 PM and 21 days for 7 PM.
The choices are not related to the environment or the animal. They are related to the researcher's availability. The researcher wanted to make about 50 measurements per time period.

When conducting one-way ANOVA to compare the means of the variable at the three different times, is the assumption of independence violated by the uneven sampling (the evening)?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "measurement"?  The inconsistency between 48+52+21 = 121 days and 50 measurements makes one wonder.  Suspicious minds will also wonder whether the researcher's availability could be associated with the animal's behavior; for instance, perhaps both are influenced by the amount of daylight.

Comment: The environment wasn't a factor (rain, shine, etc.)  The rough goal was 50 measurements for each time period.  Enough available evenings didn't happen.   The measurement is the count of a specific behavior.

Comment: (+1) is this going to be a one way ANOVA? If so then provided the equal variance assumption isn't violated (too much) you should be OK

Comment: If it's a more complex ANOVA design, imbalance may lead to a non-orthogonal design and ultimately to approximate P-values. But imbalance doesn't cause normal data to become non-normal.

Comment: One-way ANOVA.  I updated the description.

Comment: @BruceET - Re: complex design.  Although not applicable here - for purposes of a complex design, if you are talking about adding a binary variable, and using two-way ANOVA - do you have a reference handy for that being an issue?  I would just like to understand your point.

Comment: [This](https://www.ars.usda.gov/ARSUserFiles/60540520/Two-wayANOVAspreadsheet.pdf) is one discussion. Long and wordy, but elementary.

Comment: Thanks. That has several journal references.